# How to store and query user uploaded data effectively when datasets are unknown

Tags: database, postgresql, performance, storage

The "requirements" are something like this: as a user I want to upload a dataset in CSV, JSON, or other supported text formats and be able to do basic REST queries against it such as selecting all first names in the dataset or select the first 10 rows.

I'm struggling to think of the "best" way to store this data. While, off the bat I don't think this will generate millions of datasets, it seems generally bad to create a new table for every dataset for a user as, eventually, I would hit the inode limit. I could store as flat files in something like S3 that's cached but then it still does require opening and parsing the file to query it.

Is this a use case for the JSON type in Postgres? If not, what would be the "right" format and place to store this data?

Comment: A JSON file is obviously a good candidate to use a JSON(B) column type. CSV stored as a JSON array would work, too. What are the other formats?

Comment: I think most formats I can store as JSON or CSV (even CSV I can store as JSON as you mentioned). Main thing is if that'd be OK to store data like that and then query against it. i.e.` /some_user/their_api/place_names?limit=10` and their_api = the data set they provided and then limit = reading their data and limiting to 10 on the response.